# Make a column primary key when importing from excel

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am importing access documents from Excel to Access, I need the first column to become primary key but unsure the method used to do this.

**My Code:**

```
Public Sub ImportProtected(strFile As String, _
strPassword As String)
Dim oExcel As Object, oWb As Object
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oWb = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=strFile, _
Password:=strPassword)
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, _
acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "_tmp_table", strFile, -1
oWb.Close SaveChanges:=False
oExcel.Quit
Set oExcel = Nothing
End Sub
```

**I call the code using:**

```
ImportProtected "C:\Daves Work\Projects\ID.xlsm", "1234"
```

This all imports fine but I need the first column to become a primary key and have the numbers 1,2,3,4 etc in the rows that show data.

Help

Answer (score 0):

Just import the data into existing table with primary key, or better - import into temporary table, then verify imported data, then copy valid data from temporary table to working one, with primary key.

You can also create primary key using VBA after import

*UPDATE*

Missed password protection requirement, removed part of answer.

If your header changes or missing, import into temporary table with `HasFieldNames` parameter =false, then analyze first row for extracting key name (if needed), then copy the data into working table using query starting second row.

Comment: I think opening the file first is a [workaround](http://accessblog.net/2005/04/how-to-import-password-protected-excel.html) because the file has a password.

Comment: Thanks - I have imported the way you have mentioned but getting the same issue. The excel document has one header that changes daily so somehow need to make that a primary key so I can count columns

Comment: I will look in to it, thank you - A little beyond my capability I think but will have to give it a shot

Comment: @Andy G, thanks for pionting, missed this. Edited the answer

Comment: Just an advice, maybe it can help. A lot of times I'm forced to import data from Excel into Access. I use the same metod than you. What it works better for me is creating like a Template Workbook with the headers of my table and same format. Thay way I make sure the data imported is the same format of my fields. To create this workbook, in Access I export a table to Excel, delete all data excep headers and save it as blank. That exported workbook will be my template. And With VBA i just call thsat workbook, paste the values in the workbook, I save it and then I import it to Access.

Answer (score 0):

If the data you are importing is well defined - that is, you know the column names, column order and data types - then it is preferable that you import into an existing table that already has the primary key defined. You could combine this with a step that first removes any existing (previous) data from the table.

Otherwise, you will need to use Access VBA to `CreateIndex` (and set its `Primary` property) for the table definition (TableDefs). [Example](https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/907146-how-set-primary-key-vba).

---

As the column headings are not available, or cannot be relied upon, and as you need to use Excel Automation to open the file anyway, then I would first use automation to insert and create a header row; save the file, then import into a predefined Access table. For example:

```
Range("A1:D1").Value = Array("ID", "SecondField", "ThirdField", "Fourth")
```

This presumes that at least the column order and data types can be counted upon?! Otherwise, more work will be required anyway to manipulate the data.

Comment: Sadly the file being imported is not well defined and we are unable to have it changed. Column A1 changes to a unique ID daily, the other columns don't have headers at all.

Answer (score 0):

Also You can add primary key by following code

```
DoCMD.RunSQL "ALTER TABLE " & tablename & " ADD Column ID COUNTER PRIMARY KEY"
```